# Open .rtf file in my iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

How to open .rtf file in my iphone application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This sample](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle) might give you an idea